# I need to extract numbers from a String in Java

Tags: java, string, extract

In my program, I need to extract numbers from a String the given string is the following.

```
String numberOfHours = "12.0  8.0  7.0  7.0  10.0  8.0  0.0  2.0";
```

I need to extract each value into an array. When I use the split method from the String class I get a null value and also I don't get all the numbers in the array. Here's the code.

```
   String pieces[] = numberOfHours.split("  ");  

    for(int i = 0 ; i < hoursPerDay.length ; i++){
            System.out.println(pieces[i]); 
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use quantifier - `split("\\s+")`

Comment: And why are you iterating over `hoursPerDay` length, and accessing index of `pieces` array?

Comment: my bad, that was a piece of old code that I was experimenting with. srry. the split("\\s+") worked perfect.Thanks a lot! Hey MaQy, you are right!that was the problem

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
String numberOfHours = "12.0  8.0  7.0  7.0  10.0  8.0  0.0  2.0";
String pieces[] = numberOfHours.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(pieces.length);
```

prints: "8". Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: You're welcome, but please fix the code as suggested by Rohit Jain. You don't want to cycle until hoursPerDay.length, do you? ;-) pieces.length is enough.

Comment: @Dimlo - if this is a correct answer to your question could you accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String numberOfHours = "12.0  8.0  7.0  7.0  10.0  8.0  0.0  2.0";
    String pieces[] = numberOfHours.split("\\s+");
    int num[] = new int[pieces.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++){
        //must cast to double here because of the way you formatted the numbers
        num[i] = (int)Double.parseDouble(pieces[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
        System.out.println(num[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will split the array, and convert the number strings into ints as it puts them into an int array. It will output exactly what you want I've tested it